# How to upload files in asp.net 3.1 MVC with AJAX

Tags: ajax, .net-core

I'm new to asp.netcore 3.1, and now I'm learning how to upload file using AJAX in MVC, so I have tried the code that I got and here the code
in view cs.html `

Upload one or more files using this form:

```html
</p>
<input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div></div>
</form>`
```

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost("FileUpload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<IFormFile> files) {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var basePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Files\\");
        var filePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var formFile in files) {
            if (formFile.Length > 0) {
                // full path to file in temp location                   
                var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, formFile.FileName);
                filePaths.Add(filePath);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        // process uploaded files
        // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePaths });
    }
```

I tried to change this:

```
asp-controller="FileUpload" asp-action="Index">
```

The code above was made so that the action directly goes to the directed controller, but I want to change so it would pass the file to AJAX first.

Comment: You may need to use some jquery. Here you can find possibilities of how to upload file : https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky/file-uploading-with-asp-net-core-what-options-do-we-have-b5438598ada9

Comment: thanks, i managed to get the data with jQuery andchange List of IFormFile to a single IFormFile